# Is $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^{2}}$ irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, rationality-testing

Is $\sum_\limits{p}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p^{2}}$ irrational where p is prime? How to prove it?

Comment: Why do you think this is irrational? It is the sum of rational fractions only.

Comment: @Aniket It's an infinite sum.

Comment: I dont know the theory about that but if the sum is some irrational number it means that it have infinite decimals.

Comment: @Casteels You are right.. but I wanted to hear that from the OP..:-)

Comment: @Masacroso Fractions can easily have infinite decimals, e.g. $1/7=0.142857\, 142857\ldots$, the difference is that irrational numbers have infinite decimals that never repeat/don't have a period. A number is irrational if and only if its decimal representation is infinite without a period.

Comment: True @user236182, I forget completely :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $P(s)=\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}$ is called the [*prime zeta function*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html). Unfortunately the value $P(2)$ does not have a known value like $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Similarly for $P(3), P(4)$ etc. For a related discussion see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67630/convergence-of-the-series-sum-p-p-s-p-prime-and-s1). I think it is not known whether or not $P(2)$ is irrational.

Comment: This answer may help in finding the solution but it doesn't really answer the question. Not having a "known value" does not mean that rationality is unknown.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret: if there is a solution to this question - I think it is unknown.

Comment: Okay, then that is the real answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Even for $\zeta(n)$, rationality questions are very hard. And $\zeta(n)$ is much "nicer" here than $P(n)$.