# Is $\sum_{p\text{ is a prime}}\frac{1}{p^{2}}$ known to be irrational/transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is $\sum_{p\text{ is a prime}}\frac{1}{p^{2}}$ known to be irrational/transcendental? The sum exists, because $\sum_{p\text{ is a prime}}\frac{1}{p^{2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$.

Comment: Nice question -- I doubt the answer is known to humanity but perhaps someone else will chime in and prove this wrong! Perhaps worth asking on MathOverflow if you don't get a response here in a few days.

Comment: That's $P(2)$ where $P$ is the [Prime Zeta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html). There is a connection to Riemann Zeta: $$P(2)=\sum_p{1\over p^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\mu(k)\over k}\log(\zeta(2k))=0.4522474200\dots$$ This value is also the OEIS entry [A085548](https://oeis.org/A085548). There is a similar question already: [Is $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^{2}}$ irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1569661/318073) - where they say that it is not known whether it is rational or not. But, I do not know if there have been any new insights since then.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820448/irrationality-of-the-values-of-the-prime-zeta-function).